# WPF Listbox add item with Template

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I searched everywhere but I didn't found any good example or tutorial for this. I have a listbox and I made an ItemTemplate for it:

XAML :

```
  <ListBox x:Name="LB_Playlist" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="454" Margin="0,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource PlayListItem}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="PlayListItem">
                    <Grid d:DesignWidth="127" d:DesignHeight="105" Width="128" Height="128">
                        <Label x:Name="L_PlayListName" Content="{Binding Path=PlayList_Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="16" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="#26000000" Padding="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="BankGothic Lt BT"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.Resources>
  </ListBox>
```

How can I add a new Item using code (dynamic) changing L_PlayListName content everytime with different name? I need to make a new class or something? I have a button to add new Item. How can I do this?

Comment: template you mean a style? or a item template? can you show what you're attempts?

Comment: @sexta13, the question author *did* add code, but it was hidden because they didn't put a new line before it... I've just fixed it.

Comment: It seems like you just need to Raise a PropertyChanged event 
on PlayList_Name Property , Or are you asking how to changed the Entire ItemsTemplate on the fly ?

Comment: I would say that no ItemsSource is binded....

Comment: I tried something like normal PlayList.Items.Add("TEST"); and it adds new item with template but of course it doesn't modify the Label. How can I bind ItemsSource?

Comment: @sexta13 i think maybe i removed his ItemsSource in my Edit .
Kuba please Edit the xaml to include your ItemsSource ( if any such thing exists )

Comment: I Just pasted my code like it is. Without useless code.

Comment: @KubaWasilczyk in your Template you are Binding to a Property called 
PlayList_Name , what object is that in  ?

u do not have an ItemsSource ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a collection property in your code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> PlayListNames { get; set; }
```

Then `Bind` this to the `ListBox.ItemsSource`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PlayListNames}" ... />
```

Change your XAML slightly:

```
<Label x:Name="L_PlayListName" Content="{Binding}" />
```

This will `Bind` to the whole value provided to each item and in this case, that means one of the `string` values from the collection.

Finally, just set your `DataContext` of your `Window`. There are several ways to do this and the easiest (but not best) is to do this in your `MainWindow.xaml.cs` constructor:

```
DataContext = this;
```

That's it... let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Works as it should. And if I want to add more labels and edit them? Like Playlist name and let's say first song name. Two labels one below another. Can I do this same way or it will be way more difficult?

Comment: It will be mostly the same. However, you will need to create a data type class (which *should* implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface) and define a property for each field that you want to display. Then just replace the `ObservableCollection<string>` property for a `ObservableCollection<PlayList>` property (or whatever you call your type). Finally, you'll need to set the `Binding` on the `Label`s like you did in your question, using the property names... everything else should remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListBox Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
</Grid>
```

in front of Binding u can write name of  table's column (table of database)

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BindData();          
}

private void BindData()
{
    DataSet dtSet = new DataSet();
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);              
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();          
        connection.Open();
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(dtSet, "Customers");
        listBox1.DataContext = dtSet;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O'k if your just adding strings to your playlist you should edit the template to the following

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="PlayListItem">         
     <Label x:Name="L_PlayListName" Content="{Binding}" />           
  </DataTemplate>
```

But you should use an ObservableCollection and make it easy and correct .